# Changing a property of my ObservableObject instance doesn't update View. Code:

Tags: swift, observable, swiftui

//in ContentView.swift:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var app_state_instance : AppState //this is set to a default of false.

var body: some View {

if self.app_state_instance.complete == true {

Image("AppIcon")

}}

public class AppState : ObservableObject {

    @Published var inProgress: Bool = false
    @Published var complete : Bool = false 

public static var app_state_instance: AppState? //I init this instance in SceneDelegate & reference it throughout the app via AppState.app_state_instance

...

}
```

in AnotherFile.swift:

```
AppState.app_state_instance?.complete = true
```

in SceneDelegate.swift:

```
app_state_instance = AppState( UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username"), UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password") )

AppState.app_state_instance = app_state_instance

window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(app_state_instance!))
```

This ^ does not trigger an update of my view.Anyone know why?

Also, is it possible to make a static var @ published?

Also, I'm kind somewhat new to class-based + structs-as-values paradigm, if you have any tips on improving this please do share.

I've considered using an 'inout' ContentView struct reference to update struct state from other files (as going through app_state_instance isn't working with this code).

Comment: I'm probably missing something but I see the 'inProgress' property that is @Published and, possibly, another property called 'complete' that is being updated. There is, probably, a relationship between these two properties but there is no code that would illustrate it.

Comment: I mistakenly didn't paste in the `@Published var complete: Bool` line in my question. Thank you for bringing this to my attention, I've edited my question's code. Note for anyone reading: I do have this complete var in my AppState (yet the issue remains).

Comment: I don't see anything bad in provided part of code. Do you set this `complete = true` in main thread?